# Connect AWS Kinesis Data Stream with Azure Function App

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-functions, cloud, amazon-kinesis

How to connect Kinesis Data Stream with Azure Function App as consumer, without using intermediary services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kinesis Client Library (KCL) and its documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/shared-throughput-kcl-consumers.html)

You can also use Kinesis SDK (Python, Java or Nodejs) and use "Get Records" API to fetch records from the stream.
Get Records documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html)